# react native navbar animation input text

Tags: animation, reactjs, react-native, textinput

I want to show a cancel (iptal) button, on the focus `TextInput` animation?

I did the following code, but it hasn't worked:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { cancelBtn:this.cancelBtn()};
}

cancelBtn(){
    return (<TouchableHighlight style={styles.searchTouch} onPress={this.press()}>
    <Text style={styles.searchBarText}>İptal</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>);
}

render(){
    <View style={styles.searchBar}>
        <View style={styles.searchBarBox}>
            <TextInput
                ref="searchBarInput"
                style = {styles.searchBarInput}
                placeholder = 'Mekan Ara...'
            />
        </View>
    {this.state.cancelBtn}
    </View>
}
```

How do I do this in an animated way?

img:
s.s.1 => https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7wxm.png

s.s.2 => https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYa3z.png

Comment: Are you wanting to animate it or just show/hide based on focus?

Comment: Focus of the input text input button you want to get shorter and occur cancel button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `onFocus` method of `TextInput` to trigger an animation. Reverse it with `onBlur`. Then, display the input based on whether the input is selected (state).

This example isn't tested from the styling perspective, but should give you an idea. [Make sure to read up on the Animation docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html) too.

```
constructor() {
  this.state = {
    inputLength: new Animated.Value(100), // initial value 
    isFocused: false
  }
}

onFocus() {
  Animated.timing(this.state.inputLenght, {
    toValue: 90, // or whatever value
    duration: 1000
  }).start(() => this.setState({isFocused: true}))
}

onBlur() {
  Animated.timing(this.state.inputLenght, {
    toValue: 100, // or whatever value
    duration: 1000
  }).start(() => this.setState({isFocused: false}))
}



<Animated.View style={{width: this.state.inputLength}}>
  <TextInput
    ref="input"
    onFocus={this.onFocus}
    onBlur={this.onBlur}
    ...
  />
</Animated.View>
{this.state.isFocused && (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.refs.input.blur()}><Text>Submit</Text></TouchableOpacity>
)}
```

Comment: thank you so much. code worked..
How can I remove the focus after text input focus. Cancel button is pressed?

Comment: You can place a ref to the TextInput and then invoke it by calling `this.refs.input.blur()`.